# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS content not passing to remote script

Tags: php, curl

Looking for clues why the $_POST variables are not showing up in the remote script as they should.  Have exhaustively scroured multiple online resources and tried all the standard suggestions - urlencoding the passed string, passing an array, etc. But the $_POST array stays empty.

Comment: $post_args = http_build_query(array('var'=>'content'));
  function file_getc($url)
  {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
 $result = curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
  }

  $url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
  $result = file_getc($url);
  print_r($result);

Comment: you need to pass `$post_args` into your function

Comment: SOMEBODY'S A DAMNED GENIUS...THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you add CURLOPT_POST, otherwise it wont't work

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFILED, 'fields=here&more=fields');
```

Comment: $post_args = http_build_query(array('var'=>'content'));
  function file_getc($url)
  {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
 $result = curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
  }
  $url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
  $result = file_getc($url);
  print_r($result);


And I retrieve it in the remote script with:
  $var = $_POST['var'];